# Show specific category posts on Genesis framework home page

Tags: theme-development, query-posts, genesis-theme-framework

My site has Genesis framework and a child theme. I want to show specific category posts on my home page content area. I used the simple post query

```
query_posts(‘post_status=publish&cat=33&wp_get_recent_posts()’);
```

in my `genesis/lib/structure/loops.php` file right above the `do_action( ‘genesis_before_post’ );`, but it makes no sense .
So at last I used this grid loop but using this I am still unable to show category specific posts on home page as it is not taking the category attribute.

The main problem is this: by clicking on a particular post link the post doesn’t open on a separate page it redirects to the same page.

Comment: First - **Do not alter the core**. Second - These links may help you with what you need to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Also using `query_posts()` is highly discouraged.  If you need a second loop, use `new WP_Query()` or if you want to adjust the main loop then use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Exclude_categories_on_your_main_page). If you home page is not a static page, then this should work regardless of what theme you use. (Goes in functions.php... preferably a child theme if you are working with a framework)

```
function wpa84417_include_cat( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && is_main_query() ) {
        set_query_var( 'cat', '33' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa84417_include_cat' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also code it this way:

```
function wpsites_genesis_home_category( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && is_main_query() && !is_admin()) {
        query_set( 'cat', '33' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpsites_genesis_home_category' );
```